# Adobe Flex : My swf is not working in Mozilla FireFox browser

Tags: flex4, flash-builder

My adobe flex web application project works as expected in Google Chrome, IE10 & IE11 but not in Mozilla Firefox.
However, this is not observed in desktop computers but only in laptops. The application hangs and becomes unresponsive.
I'm using Adobe Flash builder 4.6, SDK 4.6.0

Here's my laptop configuration

OS: Windows 7, service pack 1
Processor: i5
RAM: 8GB
Mozilla Firefox version 56

Adobe flash player is updated with latest version 27.0.0.130 for IE, FF, Chromium and Opera browsers.

I tried disabling harware acceleration in Flash Player settings but that didn't work either.

Is this related to any hardware driver issue ? Please help me with this.

Thanks,
Anand

Comment: We need more input regarding your project. The difference is that Chrome uses PPAPI flashPlayer but FF - NPAPI. Possibly there are some security issues, investigation needed anyway

Comment: This is likely bug https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/FP-4198555, fixed in 27.0.0.170

Comment: This was a Graphics card issue. It is now resolved by upgrading the Graphics card driver to latest version - 21.20.16.4727